# How to get the container names for all possible response pattern?

Tags: python, regex, multiline

```
sudo docker ps -a , to check the status of containers.
```

Response1:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS                                                             
NAMES
3f8ac711da37        local_discourse/app   "/sbin/boot"        23 hours ago        
Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:300-
>3000/tcp   name1
3f8ac700ba37        local_discourse/app   "/sbin/boot"        20 hours ago        
Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:300-
>3000/tcp   name2
```

I can find `STATUS` & `NAMES` for `RESPONSE1`, by using `(.*)\s{2,}(Up.*\s+)\s{2,}(\d+\..*)\s{2,}(.*)`

```
m = re.finditer('(.*)\s{2,}(Up.*\s+)\s{2,}(\d+\..*)\s{2,}(.*)', resp, re.MULTILINE)
for i, j in enumerate(m):
    dict[m.group(4)] = m.group(2)
```

Response 2 :

```
3f8ac711da37        local_discourse/app   "/sbin/boot"        23 hours ago     Exited (1) 50 minutes ago    name1
3f8ac700ba37        local_discourse/app   "/sbin/boot"        20 hours ago     Exited (135) 50 minutes ago  name2
```

I can find STATUS & NAMES for RESPONSE2, by `(.*)\s{2,}(Exit.*\s+)\s{2,}\s{2,}(.*)`

```
m = re.finditer('(.*)\s{2,}(Exit.*\s+)\s{2,}\s{2,}(.*)', resp, re.MULTILINE)
for i, j in enumerate(m):
    dict[m.group(3)] = m.group(2)
```

I'm trying to make a common regex which gets the `STATUS` & `NAME` for any kind of response (status can be `UP, Exit & Stopped`). Is it possible ?

Comment: What you have tried so far, will be good to present the code you have tried and the desired result you are looking for.

Comment: I have already included the regex patterns above, do you want me to add anything further ?

Comment: So, response two what you want as your output from your `ps -a` command?

Comment: i think you even don't need  regex you can use `subprocess.Popen` to use unix command to get this done.

Comment: @pygo : I have updated with another snippet of how i'm doing. I want "container-name" (name1 & name2 in this case) and it's "status" ('Up' followed by some text and 'Exited' followed by some text), from response. Response varies depending upon the status (Up,Exit & Stopped). i don't have response for 'Stopped' scenario. But you can refer the above responses, which i have posted.

Comment: @pygo how's that by using subprocess.open and unix command ? How's it different ? Currently, I'm logging in as SSH and getting response as above. So, now how do i  get the desired output for different output response by python-regex ?

Comment: Combining your 2 patterns above give `'(.*)\s{2,}([Up|Exit|Stopped].*\s+)\s{2,}(\d+\..*)*\s{2,}(.*)'`

Comment: @kerwei But for Response1, regex provided by you will fetch 'Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:300-
>3000/tcp' instead of 'Up 23 hours'

Comment: @kerwei Tried this '(.*)\s{2,}([Up|Exit|Stopped].*\s+)\s{2,}(\d+\..*).*\s{2,}(.*)' , this exactly works how i needed but only for Response1. doesn't work for Response2.

Comment: @kerwei Did you get my point ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to go through this now but I'm just trying to combine the 2 patterns you have up there. It should be `(.*)\s{2,}((Up|Exited|Stopped).*\s+)\s{2,}(\d+\..*|[\(\)])*\s{2,}(.*)` though, without the square brackets. I'll maybe look into it further later tonight if you still haven't managed to get it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try follows:

```
import subprocess
import re

resp = subprocess.check_output('docker ps -a', shell = True)

item = re.finditer('.*?\s{1}ago\s{2,}(.*?\s).*\s{2,}(.*)', resp, re.MULTILINE)
for i in item:
    print(' : '.join([i.group(1).strip(), i.group(2).strip()]))
```

A little explanation for re:

1. It will find the first `ago` with just one space and at least 2 space near it.
2. `(.*?\s)` will find the container status
3. Finally, the `(.*)` will find the container name.

Output something like follows:

```
Exited : mystifying_hoover
Exited : abc_1
Exited : infallible_agnesi
Exited : laughing_curran
Exited : eager_clarke
Exited : youthful_northcutt
Exited : nostalgic_mclean
Exited : jolly_turing
Created : determined_curran
Exited : peaceful_mestorf
Exited : awesome_jones
Up : cc_2
Up : celery_worker
Up : dpps
Up : celery_broker2
Up : rdebug
Up : rdebug2
Up : cassandra
```

Comment: could capture the status 'Up/Exited' , not the full status like 'Up 23 hours/mins/days/secs' 'Exited (1) 50 minutes ago'. I need full status.

Comment: Oh, if need full status: change like this line: `item = re.finditer('.*?\s{1}ago\s{2,}(.*?)\s{2,}.*\s{2,}(.*)', resp, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: Awesome,this is what i expected. Thanks Iagom.

Comment: In this regex, we are explicitly not matching to Up/Exit/Stop but using `(.*?)`. what does this mean here ?

Comment: The column after `ago` will be `Up 23 hours`, then `\s{2,}` here find the blank after `Up 23 hours`, the things between the two things, that is `(.*?)` will be the `Up 23 hours`.